# In Python I get the error: reduce() arg 2 must support iteration

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm trying to get the Newton polynomial through interpolation. Thus, I need "x" as a symbol - that is, I expect a polynomial formula at the output.

Encountered an error:

> TypeError: reduce() arg 2 must support iteration

What could be the problem?

Code:

```
from scipy.special import factorial
from sympy import symbols, prod

x = symbols('x')
string_one = [0.3091,-0.0304,-0.0271,0.0054,0.0025,-0.0016,0.0019,-0.0046,0.0099,-0.019]
x_col_list = [0.0, 0.3142, 0.6283, 0.9425, 1.2566, 1.5708, 1.885, 2.1991, 2.5133]

 # we go along the deltas of the first line:
num=1
for delta in string_one:
    # we go along the column of x's: 
    for args in x_col_list:
        polynom = round( ( delta/(factorial(num)*h**num) ), 4 )  *prod(x - args)
        num+=1
    print(polynom)
```

Comment: If you look at the traceback of the error, it should tell you what the problem is.

Comment: `prod` takes an iterable as argument (like a list). `x-args` is not an iterable. `[x - args for args in x_col_list]` would be an iterable.

Answer (score 1):

Before even running your code, and before even arriving to the `prod`, you should quickly recognize that if you run your code, you will get an error about `h` and not `prod`! And if you do run your code, you will get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 13, in <module>
    polynom = round( ( delta/(factorial(num)*h**num) ), 4 )  *prod(x - args)
NameError: name 'h' is not defined
```

Indeed the issue is that you are using `h` before defining it! Let's assume you forgot to put a line `h = 0.3141` somehwere maybe after `num = 1`.

Now you will get the error that you are talking about.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 14, in <module>
    polynom = round( ( delta/(factorial(num)*h**num) ), 4 )  *prod(x - args)
  File "...\Python\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\mul.py", line 2072, in prod
    return reduce(operator.mul, a, start)
TypeError: reduce() arg 2 must support iteration
```

Now what is the problem? Why not looking at the help text for the command `prod` that developers of it have written and is available in `sympy` package itself? For seeing a short description of a Python function, just use `help()`. So you can do the following.

```
import sympy
help( sympy.prod )
```

I'm loading sympy, then asking Python to show me any description written by the developers about the function `prod` in the module `sympy`. This is what you will see.

```
Help on function prod in module sympy.core.mul:

prod(a, start=1)
    Return product of elements of a. Start with int 1 so if only
       ints are included then an int result is returned.
    
    Examples
    ========
    
    >>> from sympy import prod, S
    >>> prod(range(3))
    0
    >>> type(_) is int
    True
    >>> prod([S(2), 3])
    6
    >>> _.is_Integer
    True
    
    You can start the product at something other than 1:
    
    >>> prod([1, 2], 3)
    6
```

So it gets something called `a` and returns product of **elements** of `a`! So `a` is a collection! Not a single value! Look at examples, for example `range(3)` is not a single number `3`, but it is `0, 1, 2`, no? But what did you give to `prod` in your code? You gave `x - args`, `x` is a single symbol x, `args` is a single value, look at the place you defined it, it is the counter of your for-loop, you asked Python to go through elements of the list `x_col_list` one by one, at each step of your for-loop, `args` contains only one of these elements, what are the elemnts in `x_col_list`, single float numbers. Check it with the following code.

```
from sympy import symbols

x = symbols('x')
x_col_list = [0.0, 0.3142, 0.6283, 0.9425, 1.2566, 1.5708, 1.885, 2.1991, 2.5133]

number = 1
for args in x_col_list:
    print( f"At step {number} of the for-loop, x - args = {x - args}.\n" )
    number += 1
```

You see? At step 2 for example, `x - args` is just one expression `x - 0.3142`. So you are asking `prod` to give you product of this single element. Mathematically you may think that product of one thing, is itself, but then why to use `prod` at all?

Now let's assume you wanted product of `x - xi` where `xi` runs through `xcol_list`, then it may help you to remember the Sigma and Pi notation of sum and product in math, you write a Big Sigma/Pi, in front of it `x - xi`, but then below the big Sigma/Pi you write `xi in x_col_list` right? Or you might have seen `i=0` below and `n-1` above. Here you can do the same. Why didn't I use `args`? Well, `args` is the counter of your for-loop, and in this line you are still inside this loop, so it is not free yet to be re-used for a different task. Even if you don't get an error, it is not a good practice.

So in the end your `prod( x - args )` will be replaced by `prod( x - xi for xi in x_col_list )`. Your code will be syntax/runtime error free, but then you should think if your code is really computing the polynomial that you wanted? That I leave to yourself.